# How to add trailer/footer in csv dataframe azure blob pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

---

i have as solution which goes like

- df1 -->dataframe 1 with having 50 columns of data
- df2 --->datarame 2 having footer/trailer 3 columns of data like Trailer,count of rows,date

so i added the remaining 47 columns as `"","","".....`  so on
so that i can union 2 dataframe:

```
df3=df1.union(df2)
```

now if i want to save

```
df3.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
  .option("header","true").mode("overwrite")\
  .save(output_blob_path);
```

so now i am getting the footer as well
like this `Trailer,400,20210805,"","","","","","",""..` and so on

if any one can suggest how to remove ,"","","",.. these double quotes from the last row
where i want to save this file  in blob container.
it would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

**You can try to define structure of data frame to treat entire row as single column for both the files and then perform union.** This way you no need to add extra columns on data frame 2 and then struck in to tricky situation to remove extra columns after union.